# If my teammates wins after I die and my respawn times out, do I still get a win?

Tags: apex-legends

I was queueing solo for Apex Legends, and was randomly grouped with some players who seemed much better than me. Unfortunately, I died early in the game and they weren't able to collect my banner before my respawn timed out. But my teammates were doing very well, and might still win.

[image: the in-game badge for a player whose "respawn timed out"]

If they win while I'm still observing, will I also get credited (in stats and post-game XP) for the win? The game is prompting me to press <kbd>esc</kbd> to return the lobby, but I might wait if I can share the win.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you still get the win, as long as you do not leave the game.

Like fortnite, and PUBG, you get the win if your team wins, even if you are dead.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you still get credit and XP for the win as long as you continue to observe until the end of the game. Here is a video clip showing the post game XP screen following such a win, as proof.